# Fading text on black background

Tags: fadein

I have the following fading code which allows me to fade in the text from white to black, but on my website i have a back backround and need to fade this from black to white, can anyone help..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Fading Text Example</title>
<script language="javascript"> 
var hcolor=255;
function Fade(direction) {
obj=document.getElementById("head1");
hcolor += direction;
if (hcolor >= 0 && hcolor < 256) {
hex=hcolor.toString(16);
if (hex.length==1) hex="0" + hex;
obj.style.color="#" + hex + hex + hex;
window.setTimeout("Fade(" + direction + ");",1);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="Fade(1);">
<h1 ID="head1" style="color:#FFFFFF;">
Fading Text Example</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you use jQuery `fadeIn` API? http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

It seems the function already includes the ability to specify direction, just pass in -1 instead of 1, and set initial `hColor` to 0. Node that in the below I've also edited the formatting slightly to clean up variable names and make it marginally cleaner / more compliant.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Fading Text Example</title>
        <script language="text/javascript"> 
            var hColor=0;
            function fade(direction) {
                obj=document.getElementById("head1");
                hcolor += direction;
                if ((hColor >= 0) && (hColor < 256)) {
                    hex=hColor.toString(16);
                    if (hex.length==1) hex="0" + hex;
                    obj.style.color="#" + hex + hex + hex;
                    window.setTimeout("fade(" + direction + ");",1);
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="fade(-1);">
    <h1 id="head1" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Fading Text Example</h1> 
</body>
```